# Ms-Access Display column value after user login

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, ms-access

I have a Microsoft Access database (.mdb). There is one table called "tblLogin". The table looks like this:

```
ID | Username | Password | Access Level
1 | admin | admin | 3
2 | staff | staff | 2
3 | user | user | 1
```

I implemented some sort of login function, the code looks like this:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

.....

username = txtUsername.text
password = txtPassword.text
Dim connection As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=server.mdb;")
Dim command As New OleDbCommand("SELECT [ID] FROM [tblLogin] WHERE [UsernameField] = username AND [PasswordField] = password", connection)
Dim usernameParam As New OleDbParameter("username", username)
Dim passwordParam As New OleDbParameter("password", password)
command.Parameters.Add(usernameParam)
command.Parameters.Add(passwordParam)

If reader.HasRows Then
     MessageBox.Show("you have authenticated successfully")
     '' update
     Dim level = reader("Access Level").ToString()
     MsgBox(level)
     '' The textbox returns the word "Access Level", not the value of 0,1,2 etc. 
     command.Connection.Close()
     command.Connection.Dispose()
End If
```

If the supplied username and password matched on the one in the database, the user is considered as logged in. The question is, I want to get the value of "Access Level" as the user has logged in, but I'm quite lost in this.

How can I get the Access Level value of the logged in user? Do I need to use the reader.GetValue etc?

Thanks!

**Update:**

```
Dim command As New OleDbCommand("SELECT [ID] FROM [tblLogin] WHERE [UsernameField] = username AND [PasswordField] = password", connection)
```

change to

```
Dim command As New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [tblLogin] WHERE [UsernameField] = username AND [PasswordField] = password", connection)
```

the culprit is actually the db command -,- I must've not enough sleep now.

Comment: What is the exact name of the fields UserName and Password (UserNameField and PasswordField)?

Comment: sorry. I just missed that. I have updated the question. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add that field in your select field list.
By the way, the parameter placeholder for OleDb is usually a single question mark. OleDb doesn't recognize the parameter by their names but just by the position of the placeholder in the command text

```
using connection = New OleDbConnection("............")
using command = New OleDbCommand("SELECT [ID], [Access Level] " & _ 
                                  "FROM [tblLogin] WHERE [Username] = ? AND " & _ 
                                  "[Password] = ?", connection)

    Dim usernameParam As New OleDbParameter("@p1", username)
    Dim passwordParam As New OleDbParameter("@p2", password)
    command.Parameters.Add(usernameParam)
    command.Parameters.Add(passwordParam)
    using (OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())

       if reader.Read() Then
          MessageBox.Show("you have authenticated successfully")

          ' Now you need to read that field and store in a variable or
          ' in some kind of user interface object....
          Dim level = reader("Access Level").ToString()

       End If
    End Using
End Using
End Using
```

Comment: Weird thing is, 

`Dim level = reader("Access Level").ToString()`
`MsgBox(level)`

When I did this, the message box displays the fieldname "Access Level". Weird.

Comment: still can't manage to display the value correctly as the value returned by reader("Access Level").ToString() is the word "Access Level" not the value 0,1,2 etc. dying -,-

Comment: I have tried to reproduce your table, but I get the correct numeric value from the field Access Level.

Comment: The "db command" is wrong. perhaps I don't have enough sleep -,- *sigh*